# A class in my Huffman code project is causing me trouble

Tags: java

I am writing a Huffman code program and I have to create a class called StringOfBits which represents a string of bit values (0 or 1).  I need help with the length method and the append methods.  I am not sure how to append the parameters in each method. Here is my code http://pastebin.com/aEJDNSKS .  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class StringOfBits extends Object {
  private StringOfBits sb;
  private CharSequence chars;   
  public StringOfBits() {
    this.sb = null;
    this.chars = null;
  }
  public StringOfBits(StringOfBits sb){
    this.chars = null;
    this.sb = sb;
  }
  public StringOfBits(CharSequence chars){
    this.sb = null;
    this.chars = chars;
  }
  public StringOfBits append(int i) {
    this.sb.append(i);
    return sb;
  }
  public StringOfBits append(CharSequence str){
    this.sb.append(str);
    return sb;
  }
  public StringOfBits append(StringOfBits bitstr){
    return this.sb.append(bitstr);
  }
  // ... more methods for char/int/boolAt, setCharAt
}
```

Comment: Always include the code in your question - do not link to some "pastebin". It'll be gone after a while, rendering the question useless.

Answer (score 0):

The field sb of class StringOfBits in a class StringOfBits isn't going to help you. You are trying to implement that class by assuming that you already have implemented it. Remove this field and decide on some class (not an interface - not CharSequence) for actually storing the characters. Then, use the operations of this class for implementing all the methods.

Below is all you need to complete the task. Go ahead and fill in all the required constructors and methods by looking at the javadoc for StringBuilder and select the method to use in the method you have to write.

```
public class StringOfBits {
    private StringBuilder sb;
    public StringOfBits(){
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
    ...
}
```

For the overloaded methods setBitAt: make sure to use the one for char from the others, i.e., convert bool to '0' (false) and '1' (true) and also int 0 and 1, and call the method with the char argument.